# Pandas concatenation producing duplicate results and headers - python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, concatenation

I am trying to compile a few years of traffic data to analyze from the CDOT website. I have used the following code to get the URL's of the data for each month and year; I need to concatenate this information into one large dataframe.

```
### LIBRARIES ###

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
import os
from os.path import basename, join
from random import randint

### SET UP ###

year = ['15','16', '17', '18', '19']
month = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08', '09','10','11','12']
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36'}

print('setup complete')


years_urls = []
for y in year:
    url = 'https://dtdapps.coloradodot.info/otis/TrafficData/GetDailyTrafficVolumeForStationByMonth/000106/true/20{}/'.format(y)
    years_urls.append(url)
    sleep(randint(4,6))

#print(years_urls)
print('got years')
urls_list = []
for m in month:
    for y in years_urls:
        full_urls = y+(m)
        urls_list.append(full_urls)

print('Combining data')

#print(urls_list)

#df = pd.concat([pd.concat(pd.read_html(u, header= 0),axis = 0)for u in urls_list],axis = 0) ## GOT FORBIDDEN ERROR
#df.to_csv('Combined_Ski_Data.csv') 


appended_data = []
print('MAKING MEGA DATA FILE')
for u, value in enumerate(urls_list):
    print(value)
    r = requests.get(value, headers = header) #Should be reading each df individually and 
    dataframe = pd.read_html(r.text, header =0)
    appended_data.append(dataframe)


#print(appended_data)

df_list =[]
df_full_list = []
for a, value in enumerate(appended_data):
    dataframes = 'df_'+str(a) #Creating unique names for DF's
    df_list.append(dataframes)
    for d in df_list:
        d = pd.DataFrame(value)
        df_full_list.append(d)


combined_df = pd.concat(df_full_list, axis = 1)


#print(combined_df)
combined_df.to_csv('Colorado_Ski_Traffic.csv')
#print(appended_data)
print('code_complete')
```

The output I get is:

```
[62 rows x 26 columns]","    Count Date Dir   0h   1h   2h   3h   4h   5h    6h  ...   15h   16h   17h   18h   19h   20h   21h   22h   23h
0   01/01/2016   P   65   71   64   69   98  168   328  ...  2173  1764  2014  1132  1070   624   391   240   152
1   01/01/2016   S  115  118   99   90   84  108   436  ...  1575  1316   998   753   607   432   326   266   201
2   01/02/2016   P  102   74   78  108  183  372   694  ...  1831  1619  2200  2196  2151  1186   714   360   269
3   01/02/2016   S  142  106   77   77  139  233   854  ...  1298  1221   912   687   549   476   332   291   205
4   01/03/2016   P  156  113  120  112  161  228   438  ...  1752  1615  1364  1328  1201   815   548   260   148
..         ...  ..  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   ...  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
57  01/29/2016   S  202  180   86  101  111  187   462  ...  2204  2390  2226  2272  2214  2182  1944   803   508
58  01/30/2016   P   88   98  163  106  101  125   233  ...  1489   774   925   924   999  1557   796   342   184
59  01/30/2016   S  259  211  113   83  101  221  1338  ...  1124   337  1229  1167  1135   495   415   308   221
60  01/31/2016   P   88   94   76   82   91  154   345  ...  1695  1322  1397  1263   967  1213  1605  1252  1066
61  01/31/2016   S  165   83   53   59   53  160  1190  ...   950   848   635   500   385   323   331   185   190

[62 rows x 26 columns]","    Count Date Dir   0h   1h   2h   3h   4h   5h    6h  ...   15h   16h   17h   18h   19h   20h   21h   22h   23h
0   01/01/2016   P   65   71   64   69   98  168   328  ...  2173  1764  2014  1132  1070   624   391   240   152
1   01/01/2016   S  115  118   99   90   84  108   436  ...  1575  1316   998   753   607   432   326   266   201
2   01/02/2016   P  102   74   78  108  183  372   694  ...  1831  1619  2200  2196  2151  1186   714   360   269
3   01/02/2016   S  142  106   77   77  139  233   854  ...  1298  1221   912   687   549   476   332   291   205
4   01/03/2016   P  156  113  120  112  161  228   438  ...  1752  1615  1364  1328  1201   815   548   260   148
..         ...  ..  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   ...  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
57  01/29/2016   S  202  180   86  101  111  187   462  ...  2204  2390  2226  2272  2214  2182  1944   803   508
58  01/30/2016   P   88   98  163  106  101  125   233  ...  1489   774   925   924   999  1557   796   342   184
59  01/30/2016   S  259  211  113   83  101  221  1338  ...  1124   337  1229  1167  1135   495   415   308   221
60  01/31/2016   P   88   94   76   82   91  154   345  ...  1695  1322  1397  1263   967  1213  1605  1252  1066
61  01/31/2016   S  165   83   53   59   53  160  1190  ...   950   848   635   500   385   323   331   185   190
```

I didn't copy the entire output as it is much too large, but it repeats only certain months and years. Any ideas on how I can get one large dataframe, no duplicates, that has only one section of headers?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to drop the columns first

```
col_names = appended_data[0].columns
```

Then merge the raw data using numpy

```
all_data = np.concatenate([df.values for df in appended_data])
```

And finally restore the column names.

```
combined_df = pd.DataFrame(data=all_data, columns=col_names)
```

This seems to be a known pitfall of pandas concat.